# How to allow nullable Guid in class property?

Tags: c#, class, data-annotations, guid, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an property in my class that i will make optional. Only probem is that the property is using Guid and is required as standard. I dont know how to make it nullable.

What im trying to accomplish is to extend the membershipprovider whit an new table, Groups, and make an one-to-many link between Group and Users.

The Property:

```
public virtual Guid GroupId { get; set; }
public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
```

So how can i make an Guid property nullable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make it `Nullable<Guid>`, aka `Guid?`:

```
public virtual Guid? GroupId { get; set; }
```

If you haven't come across nullable value types in C# before, you might want to [read up on them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx).

(Do you really need the property to be virtual, btw? Are you expecting different implementations?)

Comment: Virtual is not really used for 'different implementations' by EF, it is used to automatically load referenced objects when you navigate to them. Otherwise you'd need to explicitly load them.

Comment: @LeonCullens: Right - that may well be the case here. Unfortunately the OP didn't give any context, such as EF.

Comment: Thanks, tryed "Guid?" first. Worked great but then i did get error when i tryed to look at the data in LinqPad (sql server tool). When i used Nullable<Guid> it worked both in my application and i cud look at the table in my sql program whitout errors. So i guess that Nullable<Guid> and Guid? is not equal.

Comment: @izepax: Yes, they are. `Guid?` is simply syntactic sugar for `System.Nullable<Guid>`. "i did get error" isn't enough information to go on...

Comment: @JonSkeet: Ok, i did try again after i read your comment and now it's working just as Nullable<Guid>. So I may have done something wrong before when it didn't work. That error i meant was that i cud create an member whit null as GroupId, but when i tried to get that member from the database, not using membershipprovider, it did only return something like: System.Guid is not an nullable value.

Comment: @LeonCullens: Yes, I'm using EF

Answer (score 0):

```
Guid?
```

should be working just fine.

But I don't think that this is what you really want, as I understand correctly you want an optional relationship? In that case you should remove the GroupId property, making it an optional relationship.

The second option is to mark the relationship using something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Bla>().HasOptional(g => g.Group).WithRequired();
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding your'e example of that relationship. Do you have an link or an example whit more information?

Comment: Never mind, I think making the GroupIp nullable works just fine :)